# JBL headphone has to connect twice to get good sound quality (elementary os and mint)

Tags: linux-mint, audio, elementary-os, bluetooth

I have JBL EB50BT headphones. It connects fine. In sound configuration it shows three different modes: High Fidelity playback(A2DP Sink), Headset Head unit(HSP/HFP) and High Fidelity Capture(A2DP capture).

When I connect there is no sound at first. If I put the low quality headset head unit mode on, I get low quality sound. If I put hifi playback, only silence. Then if I reconnect, I can select hifi and get good sound. I don't understand why is this happening. Why do I have to connect always twice to be able to get sound out of hifi mode?

The problem persisted when I changed distribution from Elementary OS to Linux Mint. In Windows 10 and Android it works normally.

Comment: It is an Ubuntu [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/1577197)  There is a python script linked at the bug report that may help you connect to A2DP audio

Comment: It's definitely not a Ubuntu bug, as I've been dealing with the same situation in Fedora. It appears to be either a bluez or pulseaudio bug, and the bluez-5.39 that was supposed to improve the situation (according to that bug) didn't, because Fedora is at bluez-5.43 and nothing's changed. That script does look promising, as an annoying workaround.